# Keep state of a GridView after back from a different form

Tags: c#, list, gridview, viewstate, page-load-time

I have the following classes:

```
        [Serializable]
        public class ClientBLL
        {
        private int _Rut;
        private String _Fullname;
        private List<CreditCardBLL> _CreditCards;

        public ClientBLL(){}

        public int Rut
        {
            get { return _Rut; }
            set { _Rut = value; }
        }

        public String Fullname
        {
            get { return _Fullname; }
            set { _Fullname = value; }
        }

        public List<CreditCardBLL> CreditCards
        {
            get { return _CreditCards; }
            set { _CreditCards = value; }
        } 



        public Boolean Create()
        {
            Boolean exit = false;

            try
            {
                using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
                {
                    var clientDAL = context.Client.FirstOrDefault(client 
                    => client.Rut == Rut);

                    if (clientDAL == null)
                    {
                        clientDAL = new Client();

                        clientDAL.Rut = Rut;
                        clientDAL.Fullname = Fullname;

                        context.Client.AddObject(clientDAL);

                        exit = context.SaveChanges() > 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Client cannot be created! This 
                        Client already exists!");
                    }

                    return exit;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              MessageBox.Show("Exception (C, BLL): " + ex.Message);
            }

            return exit;
        }

        public void AddCreditCard(CreditCardBLL newCreditCard)
        {
            newCreditCard.Create(Rut);
            CreditCards.Add(newCreditCard);
        }
      }

        [Serializable]
        public class CreditCardBLL
    {
        private int _Number;
        private int _Code;
        private DateTime _ValidDate;

        public CreditCardBLL(){}

        public int Number
        {
            get { return _Number; }
            set { _Number = value; }
        }

        public int Code
        {
            get { return _Code; }
            set { _Code = value; }
        }

        public DateTime ValidDate
        {
            get { return _ValidDate; }
            set { _ValidDate = value; }
        }

        public Boolean Create(int ClientRut)
        {
            Boolean exit = false;

            try
            {
                using (DBEntities context = new DBEntities())
                {
                    var creditCardDAL = 
                    context.CreditCard.FirstOrDefault(card => card.Number 
                    == Number);

                    if (creditCardDAL == null)
                    {
                        creditCardDAL = new CreditCard();

                        creditCardDAL.Number = Number;
                        creditCardDAL.Code = Code;
                        creditCardDAL.ValidDate = ValidDate;
                        creditCardDAL.Client = ClientRut;

                        context.CreditCard.AddObject(creditCardDAL);

                        exit = context.SaveChanges() > 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Credit Card cannot be created! 
                        This Credit Card already exists!");
                    }

                    return exit;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Exception (CC, BLL): " + ex.Message);
            }

            return exit;
             }
             }
```

Code-Behind:

Clients.aspx.cs

```
        public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
        {

        private List<ClientBLL> clients;
        private List<int> pageLoads;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int number = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Number"]);
        number = number + 1;
        ViewState["Number"] = number;

        MessageBox.Show("Page_Load: " + number);

        pageLoads = (List<int>)ViewState["Index"];



        if (pageLoads == null)
        {
            pageLoads = new List<int>();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("PageLoads != null");
        }

        pageLoads.Add(number);

        MessageBox.Show("PageLoads.Count: "+pageLoads.Count);


        ViewState["Index"] = pageLoads;


        for (int i = 0; i < pageLoads.Count; i++)
        {

            int index = pageLoads.FindIndex(value => value == number);

            if (index == 3)
            {

                FillGridView();
            }


            MessageBox.Show("Index: " + index);
        }

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            gvClients.DataSource = new object[] { null };
            gvClients.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            clients = (List<ClientBLL>)ViewState["Clients"];

            if (clients == null)
            {
                clients = new List<ClientBLL>();
            }

        }

    } 

            protected void gvClients_RowCommand(object sender, 
            GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "btnAdd")
        {
            try
            {
                ClientBLL newClient = new ClientBLL();

                String strRut = ((TextBox)gvClients.FooterRow.FindControl("txtRutInsert")).Text;
                int intRut = int.Parse(strRut);
                newClient.Rut = intRut;

                String fullname = ((TextBox)gvClients.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFullnameInsert")).Text;
                newClient.Fullname = fullname;

                newClient.Create();

                clients.Add(newClient);

                ViewState["Clients"] = clients;

                FillGridView();

            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NullReferenceException (C, UI): " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("FormatException (C, UI): " + ex.Message);
            }

        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "btnCards")
        {

            var rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

            Session["Client"] = clients[rowIndex];

            String clientID;
            clientID = Session.SessionID;

            MessageBox.Show("Client Session ID (Client): " + clientID);



            Response.Redirect("CreditCards.aspx");

        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "btnDelete")
        {

        }

      }

    protected Boolean FillGridView()
    {
        Boolean flag = false;

        if (clients == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Clients is empty! Can't bind to it!");
        }
        else
        {
            gvClients.DataSource = clients;
            gvClients.DataBind();


            flag = true;
        }

        return flag;
    }
   }
```

CreditCards.aspx.cs:

```
    public partial class Cards : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

    private ClientBLL client;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {





        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["Client"] != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Session Client != null (!IsPostBack)");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Session Client == null (!IsPostBack)");
            }

            gvCreditCards.DataSource = new object[] { null };
            gvCreditCards.DataBind();


        }
        else
        {
            client = (ClientBLL)Session["Client"];

            //form1 = (HtmlForm) ViewState["Page"];



            if (client.CreditCards == null)
            {
                client.CreditCards = new List<CreditCardBLL>();
            }
        }


     }

    protected void gvCreditCards_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "btnAdd")
        {
            try
            {
                CreditCardBLL newCreditCard = new CreditCardBLL();

                String strNumber = ((TextBox)gvCreditCards.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNumberInsert")).Text;
                int intNumber = int.Parse(strNumber);
                newCreditCard.Number = intNumber;

                String strCode = ((TextBox)gvCreditCards.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCodeInsert")).Text;
                int intCode = int.Parse(strCode);
                newCreditCard.Code = intCode;

                String strValidDate = ((TextBox)gvCreditCards.FooterRow.FindControl("txtValidDateInsert")).Text;
                DateTime datValidDate = DateTime.Parse(strValidDate);
                newCreditCard.ValidDate = datValidDate;


                client.AddCreditCard(newCreditCard);

                String clientID;
                clientID = Session.SessionID;

                MessageBox.Show("Client Session ID (CreditCard): " + clientID);

                FillGridView();

            }
            catch (NullReferenceException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("NullReferenceException (CC, UI): " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("FormatException (CC, UI): " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    protected Boolean FillGridView()
    {
        Boolean flag = false;

        if (client.CreditCards == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("CreditCards is empty! Can't bind to it!");
        }
        else
        {
            gvCreditCards.DataSource = client.CreditCards;
            gvCreditCards.DataBind();



            flag = true;
        }

        return flag;
    }

    protected void btnBackToClients_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["Client"] != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Client's Session != null (Back to Clients)");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Client's Session == null (Back to Clients)");
        }

        String rut, number;

        rut = client.Rut.ToString();
        number = client.CreditCards[0].Number.ToString();

        MessageBox.Show("Client's rut: " + rut + " CreditCard's number: " + number);


        String clientID;
        clientID = Session.SessionID;

        MessageBox.Show("Client Session ID (CreditCard) after closing the current one: " + clientID);

        //Session testing
        Boolean testing = true;

        Session["Test"] = testing;

        Response.Redirect("Clients.aspx");
    }
   }
```

Well, the situation is that in Clients.aspx.cs I have a list of Clients in a GridView, each Client has its own list of CreditCards. When I click to add new CreditCards of a specific Client, it will redirect to CreditCards.aspx.cs, whereas it has a list in a GridView of the current Client's CreditCards that was clicked before, after adding the whished CreditCards. Here comes the tricky part. Everytime I want to back to Clients.aspx.cs, Clients list (GridView) is gone, I need to keep it alive to be able to manage Clients. On the other hand, need to Display the list of CreditCards (GridView) according to the clicked Client.

I've tried a lot, but I can't figure it out!!!

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: How are you going back to the client list page from credit card page? Did you debug the code and check what's going wrong here? What is the use of `payloads` and `number` variables in clients.aspx page_load?

Comment: I wanted to use it as a tracker, in this case, the "number", to count the Page_Loads, and set each number to the list's Indexes. thus when the list reach the index[3], display the Clients.aspx.cs GridView, that index[3] is when I back to the previous page, but, this method didn't work.

Comment: You loose the viewstate once you redirect to other page. So when you come back from CreditCards page, index and pageloads will be empty lists which will not allow for loop to execute and fillgridview method won't be executed ever. So you need to correct this logic.

Comment: That is why I'm asking. I can't figure it out. Can you at least give me an idea please?

Comment: I could use Session, but, I don't want to CreditCards.aspx.cs manage the other's page state.

Comment: Are you setting `ViewState["Number"]` and `ViewState["Index"]` in some event of Listbox? Can you please explain logic of it? Why can't you handle all the logic in that event only instead of setting ViewState values?

Comment: ViewState["Number"] and ViewState["Index"] are for count the Page_Loads to know when to apply the FillGridView to display the clients, I found that Index[3], number turns 1, is when I back to Clients page, but, as I said, I didn't work. What did you mean with "Why can't you handle all the logic in that event only instead of setting ViewState values?" ?.

Comment: Please, something, even a concept.

Comment: Why you need to count the page_loads to call `FillGridView` method? I want to understand business logic of that? Is like you have 3 items in the listbox and when you select 3rd item in it, you want to call `FillGridView`? Or you have a Wizard kind of page where user clicks on "Next" button to see the next screen and you are tracking that via viewstate so that when user clicks on "Next" 3rd time you want to call `FillGridView` method to display clients?

Comment: That 3rd item was for a predictable case, i.e, testing case, but in a real event this wont work at all. The 3rd moment or item is the backward moment, when the GridView of clients is shown on Client page, but, again, this can't work. The second question was correct, but it wont work. The deal is... In the moment when you comeback from the CreditCard page, the GridView w/  the added clients should be displayed. At this time, any moment I return to it, the list of Clients is gone. Here is the Project if you want to: http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1499824313